# Navigate to Page (WebBrowser) not showing properly

Tags: c#, html, browser

I have a WebBrowser (WinPhone C#) where I set the NavigateToString in CodeBehind. The complete code is this here:

```
string f = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ' -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' ><script type='text/javascript'>function get_radio_value(test){ var elements = document.getElementsByName(test); for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){if (elements[i].checked){var rad_val = elements[i].value;return rad_val;}}}</script><title>Kundenfragebogen</title></head><body><h1>Kundenfragebogen</h1><form name='myForm' action=''><table border='2'><tr><td></td><td>sehr gut</td><td>gut</td><td>schlecht</td></tr><tr><td>Wie geht es Ihnen?</td><td><input type='radio' name='1' value='1'/>Mir ging es noch nie besser!</td><td><input type='radio' name='1' value='2'/>Es geht mir so wie immer.</td><td><input type='radio' name='1' value='3'/>Heute geht einfach gar nichts…</td></tr><tr><td>Können Sie Auto fahren?</td><td><input type='radio' name='2' value='1'/>Ja</td><td></td><td><input type='radio' name='2' value='3'/>Nein</td></tr><tr><td>Möchten Sie unseren Newsletter abonnieren?</td><td><input type='radio' name='3' value='1'/>Ja</td><td></td><td></td></tr></table></form></body></html>";
webbrowser.NavigateToString(f);
```

When I do it like this, the WebBrowser only shows the code and not the actual HTML site (with RadioButtons, ...). When I do it like this:

```
string f = "\"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ' -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' ><script type='text/javascript'>function get_radio_value(test){ var elements = document.getElementsByName(test); for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){if (elements[i].checked){var rad_val = elements[i].value;return rad_val;}}}</script><title>Kundenfragebogen</title></head><body><h1>Kundenfragebogen</h1><form name='myForm' action=''><table border='2'><tr><td></td><td>sehr gut</td><td>gut</td><td>schlecht</td></tr><tr><td>Wie geht es Ihnen?</td><td><input type='radio' name='1' value='1'/>Mir ging es noch nie besser!</td><td><input type='radio' name='1' value='2'/>Es geht mir so wie immer.</td><td><input type='radio' name='1' value='3'/>Heute geht einfach gar nichts…</td></tr><tr><td>Können Sie Auto fahren?</td><td><input type='radio' name='2' value='1'/>Ja</td><td></td><td><input type='radio' name='2' value='3'/>Nein</td></tr><tr><td>Möchten Sie unseren Newsletter abonnieren?</td><td><input type='radio' name='3' value='1'/>Ja</td><td></td><td></td></tr></table></form></body></html>";
webbrowser.NavigateToString(f);
```

it's working! I only set at the beginning \". The page is being displayed, but the " is right on top of my site. Why the f... do I have to write \" at the start of my string for the "html-file"?

edit: this one is shorter, but the same problem:

Not working:

```
string f = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' ><title>Kundenfragebogen</title></head><body><h1>Kundenfragebogen</h1>asdas</body></html>";
webbrowser.NavigateToString(f);
```

working:

```
string f = "\"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' ><title>Kundenfragebogen</title></head><body><h1>Kundenfragebogen</h1>asdas</body></html>";
webbrowser.NavigateToString(f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a bug in WP8 but there are two workarounds. One way is to save the HTML file into the isolated storage and use the `WebBrowser.Navigate()` method to open the URI. You don't need to modify the HTML file if you use that method.

The alternative is to remove the declaration at the top (`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>`) so your string would be

```
string f = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' ><script type='text/javascript'>function get_radio_value(test){ var elements = document.getElementsByName(test); for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){if (elements[i].checked){var rad_val = elements[i].value;return rad_val;}}}</script><title>Kundenfragebogen</title></head><body><h1>Kundenfragebogen</h1><form name='myForm' action=''><table border='2'><tr><td></td><td>sehr gut</td><td>gut</td><td>schlecht</td></tr><tr><td>Wie geht es Ihnen?</td><td><input type='radio' name='1' value='1'/>Mir ging es noch nie besser!</td><td><input type='radio' name='1' value='2'/>Es geht mir so wie immer.</td><td><input type='radio' name='1' value='3'/>Heute geht einfach gar nichts…</td></tr><tr><td>Können Sie Auto fahren?</td><td><input type='radio' name='2' value='1'/>Ja</td><td></td><td><input type='radio' name='2' value='3'/>Nein</td></tr><tr><td>Möchten Sie unseren Newsletter abonnieren?</td><td><input type='radio' name='3' value='1'/>Ja</td><td></td><td></td></tr></table></form></body></html>";
webbrowser.NavigateToString(f);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the declaration and it's working, but I'll also try it with isolated storage. I used the string in my Windows 8 App and in my WPF-program and it worked, but suddenly in WP8 it didn't work anymore... Would be great if someone could tell me why it's not working. Did Microsoft do this on purpose?...

Comment: I'm very sure it worked on WP7 so either it's a bug with WP8 or they removed it but I'm not sure why they'd want to remove it so I'm guessing it's a bug.

Comment: If you get a response, please post back. Would be good to know for sure what the reason is!

Comment: Just found a blog, where a user also faced this issue (+ solution): http://mikaelkoskinen.net/webbrowser-navigatetostring-broken-in-windows-phone-8-and-also-affects-windows-phone-7-apps-solution-included/
 I've also contacted Microsoft https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/791131/doctype-not-working-in-wp8

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted Microsoft. This is their answer:

Greetings from Microsoft Connect!

```
This notification was generated for feedback item: DOCTYPE not working in WP8 which you submitted at the Microsoft Connect site.

Thank you for submitting this Connect issue. The issue you reported appears to be on a released Windows Phone Product. As we only accept feedback on Visual Studio & .Net Framework through this site, we have notified the Windows Phone team and are closing this issue. If this issue is severe, causing critical business situations or blocking your product development or deployment, please go to http://support.microsoft.com for assistance. To post a question or receive community support for developing Windows Phone apps, consider posting your question or concern on the Windows Phone Development forum. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/category/wpapps.

You may receive a general "Feedback Item Updated" notification as well, if any other changes were made by Microsoft.

Thank you for using Microsoft Connect!

Regards,

the Microsoft Connect Team
```